# Bit shift multiple times or store shift once as mask

Tags: c++, c, arm, bit-manipulation, cortex-m

I am using a loop to manipulate a number of variables using bit values as I go.  I have noticed that I am using the expressions `if (some_state & (1 << i))`, and `some_var &= ~(1 << i)` dozens of times before `i` is incremented.

This routine must be executed in on a regular interrupt, and my main clock is not all that fast, so I am wondering if this is the best I can do.  In my head this is a lot of operations.

Maybe I could could store the shifted value and use it instead.

```
for (int i=0; i<MAX; ++i) {
  uint32_t mask_value = (1 << i);
  if (some_state & mask_value) {
    if (! --some_array[i].timer_value) {
      some_var |= mask_value;
      another_var &= ~mask_value;
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Does there appear to be any clear answer? Perhaps this is more of a situation where the compiler may optimize to some unknown level, so who can know until I run the routines 10,000 times, time them, and compare?

**UPDATE:**

I'm running GNU ARM Embedded Toolchain for my NXP LPC11 ARM (Cortex-M0) microcontroller.

Should be reasonable enough to review assembly in the IDE (LPCXpresso, Eclipse based) and to profile it.

Comment: Which CPU architecture are you using? Different architectures have different instructions for handling shifts, some are faster, some may be slower. You should match your operations to the more efficient instructions you CPU supports

Comment: Why not benchmark it in your specific environment? We don't know much about your hardware, your compiler etc.

Comment: Run the routines at least 10,000 times, time them and compare. If possible, multiple times and with all kinds of data. That is the only true way to find out what is faster. Everything else is speculation. FWIW, I **guess** calculating the mask only once is faster, but I may be wrong, as it could depend on the compiler, the platform, etc.

Comment: In any case you can generate the assembly code generated and examine the output in both options

Comment: The assembly code is not enough. Real profiling/testing/timing/benchmarking/whatever you call it is the only proper way to find out.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Right, but it does give a rough estimation. You can get pretty close to the real output if you measure how many clocks each individual instruction takes and calculate the time with the CPU frequency. You can also estimate the memory fetch operation times if you really wanted to, but for this question I think the rough estimation will be enough - storing the shifted value is 99% to be the right choice

Comment: I also think that shifting once and then storing the value is the right way, but instead of staring at assembly and guessing and assuming this or that, I would simply profile the code. Anything else is speculative and probably a lot more work as well.

Comment: Write your code as you find best. Compile with maximum optimization. Profile it. Do you have a performance issue? If no, just move on. In most cases it is best to write clear readable code and leave the rest to the compiler. Compiler optimizations can often beat anything we can come up with by writing "clever" code.

Comment: Instead of `for(i=15;i>=0;i--){ mask = 1<<i; ... }` may I suggest `for(mask=0x8000;mask;mask>>=1){...}`

Comment: You may suggest it, you may!

Comment: I actually need to use use the regular integer increments in order to index arrays in my code.  But I haven't experimented much with more novel for loop instructions, so that is an invaluable piece of advice to help stay out of the box.

Comment: If your processor supports it, have a look at bitbanding. You might find a quicker solution, but you might not. Worth a look though!

Comment: `uint32_t mask_value = (1 << i);` is not portable code.  Suggest `uint32_t mask_value = (1UL << i);`

Comment: It _might_ be more efficient to explicitly pre-generate the mask so that the 2-3 instructions involved only appear once, but on the flipside if there's lots of other work in between places it's used and the register pressure from an extra variable forces the compiler to spill to the stack more often, maybe it hurts more overall... Note that [CSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_subexpression_elimination) is the bread-and-butter of a modern optimising compiler, so where it's worthwhile it's probably already being done for you.

Comment: Perhaps you could just unroll the outer for loop? Be sure to time the result etc etc

Comment: Do not forget const correctness. Consider using `const uint32_t mask_value = (1UL << i);`